# How to handle outliers in GARCH model?

Tags: outliers, garch

In GARCH model how should I handle outliers?
Just remove it from my dataset and skip to next data entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

generally speaking, outliers should *never* be dealt with that way. You have even more reasons not handle them this way in time series context for obvious reasons. The solution is to use an outlier robust estimation technique (one where the suspect observations are left in the data set, but where their influence over the final estimates is bounded). Two pointers to robust garch estimation models:

[Yohai and Muler (2005)](http://ulises.ic.fcen.uba.ar/preprints/muler-yohai2005.pdf)

[Boudt and *al.* (2011)](http://www.riskresearch.org/files/KB-JD-SL-38.pdf)